# how to replace array item in content java script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this html codes :

```
<p class="Chords">[A]     [B]    [C]</p>
<p> Some Text Goes Here </p>
<p class="Chords">[D]     [E]    [F]</p>
<p> Some Text Goes Here </p>
<p class="Chords">[G]     [H]    [I]</p>
<p> Some Text Goes Here </p>
<p class="Chords">[J]     [K]    [L]</p>
<p> Some Text Goes Here </p>
```

And I have array like this

```
["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12"]
```

I want replace my array item in p tag that has Chords class And my Content should be like this one :

```
<p class="Chords"> 1     2    3</p>
<p> Some Text Goes Here </p>
<p class="Chords"> 4     5    6</p>
<p> Some Text Goes Here </p>
<p class="Chords"> 7     8    9</p>
<p> Some Text Goes Here </p>
<p class="Chords"> 10     11    12</p>
<p> Some Text Goes Here </p>
```

Comment: Please show us what you tried.

Comment: And, what's the problem?

Comment: [How much effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3082296)

Comment: @04FS I don't know what is the exactly solution for this ... i think my array should created line by line and array of array ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it like this, first you have to extract all the characters required to be replaced then loop through them and find the value for each character from the array using charCode.

```js
const array = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"]

const places = $("#container").html().match(/\[[A-Z]\]/g)

places.forEach(char => {
  const index = char.charCodeAt(1) - 65
  const template = $("#container").html();
  $("#container").html(template.replace(char, array[index]))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <p class="Chords">[A] [B] [C]</p>
  <p> Some Text Goes Here </p>
  <p class="Chords">[D] [E] [F]</p>
  <p> Some Text Goes Here </p>
  <p class="Chords">[G] [H] [I]</p>
  <p> Some Text Goes Here </p>
  <p class="Chords">[J] [K] [L]</p>
  <p> Some Text Goes Here </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex to replace [value] `text.replace(/\[(.*?)\]/g`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var arr = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12"];
  var text = $("#text").text();
  var count = -1;
  $("#text").text(text.replace(/\[(.*?)\]/g, function() {
    count = count + 1;
    return arr[count]
  }));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='text'>
<p class="Chords">[A]     [B]    [C]</p>
<p> Some Text Goes Here </p>
<p class="Chords">[D]     [E]    [F]</p>
<p> Some Text Goes Here </p>
<p class="Chords">[G]     [H]    [I]</p>
<p> Some Text Goes Here </p>
<p class="Chords">[J]     [K]    [L]</p>
<p> Some Text Goes Here </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get all the `p` elements with class `Chords` and then iterate over the arr incrementing it with +3 and replace the textContent of your `p`.

```js
const arr = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12"];

const pEles = document.querySelectorAll('.Chords');

for(let i = 0, j = 0; i < arr.length; i = i+3, j++) {
    pEles[j].textContent = `${arr[i]} ${arr[i+1]} ${arr[i+2]}`;
}
```

```html
<p class="Chords">[A] [B] [C]</p>
<p> Some Text Goes Here </p>
<p class="Chords">[D] [E] [F]</p>
<p> Some Text Goes Here </p>
<p class="Chords">[G] [H] [I]</p>
<p> Some Text Goes Here </p>
<p class="Chords">[J] [K] [L]</p>
<p> Some Text Goes Here </p>
```

Comment: This will not work, if the order of the placeholders is changed